# How to get Linux to recognize an unidentified touchpad?

Tags: x11, touchpad, input, laptop

The Lenovo Yoga 720 has a touchpad that shows up in lsusb with a bus ID of 06cb:0081. 06cb is the vendor ID for Synaptics. A quick Google search for the that string brings no results except other people trying to get the touchpad working on the 720.

This leads me to believe that this is a new device. This machine only came out a couple of months ago and is probably not listed in whatever table of device IDs that libinput or some other driver uses to match devices up with their features. I would think that a generic mouse module would of provided some functionality, but this is not the case.

Is there a place where I can tell Linux to match up that bus ID with the touchpad driver? From the reading I have done about this, it seems like touchpad drivers are usually done outside of the kernel level and though the X server, and through libinput using uinput.

So if anyone has any ideas or suggestions please share them.

Some other details:

The only place anything touchpad related seems to appear is `lsusb`:

```
 Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:5621 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c245 Logitech, Inc. G400 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output of xinput --list is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID 50F8 Finger                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Gaming Mouse G400                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ EasyCamera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Wacom HID 50F8 Pen                        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
   ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The output of cat /proc/bus/input/devices is

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event0  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:17/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0                                                                  
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2                              
U: Uniq=                                                                                       
H: Handlers=kbd event2                                                                         
B: PROP=0                                                                                      
B: EV=3                                                                                        
B: KEY=10000000000000 0                                                                        

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000                                              
N: Name="Power Button"                                                                         
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0                                                                 
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event3  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd rfkill event4  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=101400800100c03 400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event5  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0010 Vendor=001f Product=0001 Version=0100
N: Name="PC Speaker"
P: Phys=isa0061/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=40001
B: SND=6

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=056a Product=50f8 Version=0100
N: Name="Wacom HID 50F8 Pen"
P: Phys=i2c-WCOM50F8:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-21/i2c-WCOM50F8:00/0018:056A:50
F8.0002/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 mouse0  
B: PROP=2
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=1c03 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000003
B: MSC=1

I: Bus=0018 Vendor=056a Product=50f8 Version=0100
N: Name="Wacom HID 50F8 Finger"
P: Phys=i2c-WCOM50F8:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-21/i2c-WCOM50F8:00/0018:056A:50
F8.0002/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 mouse1  
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=13d3 Product=5621 Version=1611
N: Name="EasyCamera"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-8/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event10  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event15  
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

Comment: read this, about your ID of 06cb:0081 https://github.com/mshammas/Validity90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same machine, the touchpad is actually an ELAN651 device, hooked through the I2C bus. The USB id you see is that of the fingerprint reader.

Support for this touchpad was added to the kernel somewhat recently, around 4.14, see the related thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Lenovo/comments/6ebgbc/with_the_yoga_720_15_touchpad_not_working_on_linux/ . With the right kernel version, it should work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a synaptics touchpad, you could give the synaptics driver a chance. Install it with:

```
$ sudo pacman -S xf86-input-synaptics
```

You can then copy over the default configuration file to make use of it:

```
$ cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf
```

This is what helped me in a similar case. Source: [Arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics)

The section [Touchpad device is not located at /dev/input/*](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Touchpad_device_is_not_located_at_.2Fdev.2Finput.2F.2A) has helped me too.